# Хочу убрать тире после каждого нажатия на пробел

Tags: python

Мой код:

```
def shifr_A1Z26(message, key):
    result=[]

    alf = ['','А','Б','В','Г','Д','Е','Ё','Ж','З','И','Й','К','Л','М','Н','О','П','Р','С','Т',
           'У','Ф','Х','Ц','Ч','Ш','Щ','Ъ','Ы','Ь','Э','Ю','Я']

    alf2 = ['','а','б','в','г','д','е','ё','ж','з','и','й','к','л','м','н','о','п','р','с','т',
            'у','ф','х','ц','ч','ш','щ','ъ','ы','ь','э','ю','я']

    for txt in message:
        if txt.isupper() and txt!=' ':
            mes=alf.index(txt)
            mes=str(mes)
            result.append(mes)
            result.append('-')
        elif txt==' ':
            result.append(' ')
        else:
            if txt!=' ':
                mes=alf2.index(txt)
                mes=str(mes)
                result.append(mes)
                result.append('-')
            else:
                result.append(' ')              
    result=result[:-1]
    return "".join(result)
```

Не могу понять, почему после каждого нажатия на пробел ставится тире, хотя в программе написано, что если пробел, то поставить пробел

Comment: Покажите пример входных и выходных данных. Сейчас непонятно, как здесь добиться появления тире, у меня на месте пробела появляется пробел

Comment: входное данное- любой текст, но без знаков, а выходные данные- порядковые номера букв слова в алфавите, написанные через тире, и если между словами есть пробел, то и между числами тире, но вместе с пробелом еще и тире ставится

Comment: изменил в вопросе

Comment: Теперь я на `тест тест` получил `20-6-19-20- 20-6-19-20`. Видим, что после пробела никаких тире нету, тире стоит только после кода символа `т` перед пробелом

Comment: ну смотрите, после кода для первого слова стоит тире лишнее, как его можно убрать?

Comment: Например, переделать алгоритм так, чтобы тире добавлялось не после текущего символа, а перед следующим

Comment: он должен быть между числами, а не там, где должен быть пробел

Comment: То есть добавлять тире перед символом с проверкой наподобие `if result and result[-1] != ' ' and txt != ' ': result.append('-')`

Comment: а вы уверены в исправности данной строки?

Comment: Да, у меня работает

Comment: что у вас получилось в итоге?

Comment: и я немного не понял, куда надо эту строчку вставить, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: через '-'.join([...])  надо бы)

Comment: нет, а куда вы вставили ту строчку, которую вы предложили выше, чтобы программа заработала ( я про это if result and result[-1] != ' ' and txt != ' ': result.append('-') )

Comment: Приведите пример входных данных, вывода программы и объясните, почему вывод неправильный.

Answer (score 2):

Я не буду исправлять ваш код, а перепишу с нуля.

Алгоритм такой:

1. Разбить текст на отдельные слова по пробелу (метод `split`)
2. В каждом слове символ заменить на его код
3. Список номеров собрать вместе в одну строку с разделителем `'-'` с помощью метода `join`
4. Полученные списки кодов объединю в одну строку с разделителем `' '`

```
def shifr_A1Z26(message, key):
    result=[]  # Здесь будет список кодированных слов вида ['123-334-533', '11-12', ...]

    alf = ['','А','Б','В','Г','Д','Е','Ё','Ж','З','И','Й','К','Л','М','Н','О','П','Р','С','Т',
           'У','Ф','Х','Ц','Ч','Ш','Щ','Ъ','Ы','Ь','Э','Ю','Я']

    for word in message.split(' '):
        encoded_word = []  # Здесь будет список кодов символов в слове вида ['123', '334', '553']

        # Сразу приводим все слово к верхнему регистру,
        # чтобы избавиться от отдельного массива для нижнего регистра
        for char in word.upper():
            encoded_word.append(str(alf.index(char)))

        result.append('-'.join(encoded_word))    

    return " ".join(result)


print(shifr_A1Z26("Привет Мир", None))  # Вывод: 17-18-10-3-6-20 14-10-18
```

Та же функция в более компактном виде:

```
def shifr_A1Z26(message, key):
    alf = ['','А','Б','В','Г','Д','Е','Ё','Ж','З','И','Й','К','Л','М','Н','О','П','Р','С','Т',
           'У','Ф','Х','Ц','Ч','Ш','Щ','Ъ','Ы','Ь','Э','Ю','Я']      

    return " ".join('-'.join(str(alf.index(char))
                        for char in word.upper())
                            for word in message.split(' '))
```

Comment: а можно ли к этой программе расшифровку написать?

Comment: @Tiranich, я написал. Что конкретно вам не понятно?